# Problems installing JSCover 0.2.0 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cygwin

I am trying to install JSCover 0.2.0 on Windows 7. 
I was using [this guide](http://lucaspaulger.com/code-quality/2013/01/07/JSCover-Guide/), but failed on step 2 where I need to run the example-server.sh
Do I need to run it from windows command line, or cygwin console. 
From running from windows console I get this error
[image]

And from Cygwin console nothing happens (ignore the java error I had example-server.sh file open at the time)

[image]

I must be missing some step here. Does anyone fell into same problem, or maybe do you have better installation guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me being stupid.
When server runs using cygwin it does not give any message about it, it just runs.
So simply browse to `http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html?/index.html` and that should take you to example page.

One more thing you do not need cygwin to run JSCover 0.2.0 there is `example-server.bat` in JSCover-0.2.0 directory that you can run to start the server on Windows.